# Upgrading to angular5+ .. the '@angular/router' doesn't work

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

I was trying to use date-time picker in angular4 . Almost all of date/time pickers require upgrading to angular5+. So i updated my angular using two commands -

Update the Angular packages using the following commands.
npm install -g npm-check-updates
and ncu -u

from the website -

http://www.talkingdotnet.com/upgrade-angular-4-app-angular-5-visual-studio-2017/

And the changes are -

**package.json**

```
 @angular/cdk                              ^5.2.5  →  ^6.0.1
 @angular/common                            4.3.4  →   6.0.0
 @angular/compiler                          4.3.4  →   6.0.0
 @angular/core                              4.3.4  →   6.0.0
 @angular/forms                             4.3.4  →   6.0.0
 @angular/http                              4.3.4  →   6.0.0
 @angular/material                         ^5.2.5  →  ^6.0.1
  @angular/platform-browser                  4.3.4  →   6.0.0
 @angular/platform-browser-dynamic          4.3.4  →   6.0.0
 @angular/router                            4.3.4  →   6.0.0
 @angular/upgrade                           4.3.4  →   6.0.0
 @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap         ^1.0.0-beta.6  →  ^2.0.0
 angular-2-local-storage                   ^1.0.1  →  ^2.0.0
 chart.js                                   2.6.0  →   2.7.2
 core-js                                    2.5.0  →   2.5.6
 localstorage                              ^0.1.0  →  ^1.0.1
 moment                                    2.18.1  →  2.22.1
 ng-pick-datetime                          ^5.2.6  →  ^6.0.1
 ng4-loading-spinner                       1.0.27  →   1.1.3
 ngx-bootstrap                              1.8.1  →   2.0.5
 restify                                   ^6.3.4  →  ^7.1.1
 rxjs                                       5.4.3  →   6.1.0
 zone.js                                   0.8.16  →  0.8.26
 @angular/cli                              ^1.7.3  →  ^6.0.0
 @angular/compiler-cli                      4.3.4  →   6.0.0
 @types/jasmine                            2.5.53  →   2.8.7
 @types/node                               8.0.20  →  10.0.6
 codelyzer                                  3.1.2  →   4.3.0
 jasmine-core                               2.7.0  →   3.1.0
 jasmine-spec-reporter                      4.2.0  →   4.2.1
 karma                                      1.7.0  →   2.0.2
 karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter           1.3.0  →   1.4.2
 karma-jasmine                              1.1.0  →   1.1.2
 karma-jasmine-html-reporter                0.2.2  →   1.0.0
 protractor                                 5.1.2  →   5.3.1
 ts-node                                    3.3.0  →   6.0.3
 tslint                                     5.6.0  →  5.10.0
 nodemon     ^1.17.3  →  ^1.17.4
 primeng      ^5.2.5  →   ^5.2.6
 sass         ^1.3.0  →   ^1.3.2
 typescript   ^2.3.4  →   ^2.8.3
 Upgraded /home/dell/Downloads/Datshare/Adaani5.0 (another 
   copy).0/package.json
```

And then i run this command -

```
     npm install  ng2-simple-timepicker
```

I want to use timepicker from here -

```
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-simple-timepicker
```

But  then still it is not recognising

```
 import { TimePickerModule } from "ng2-simple-timepicker/timepicker";


 import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'
 import { Http, Response, Headers, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

 import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from 
 '@angular/forms';
```

It says Cannot find module '@angular/forms',etc

Please why are these modules not recognizable

Comment: try running the command `npm install @angular/router`

Comment: Have you tried `npm install @angular/forms --save'.

Comment: i am getting error for this also - Cannot find module '@angular/http'  and Cannot find module '@angular/forms'  and Cannot find module 'ng2-simple-timepicker/timepicker' even though i run the command npm install  ng2-simple-timepicker

Comment: `npm-check-updates` is upgrading your existing application to Angular 6 not 5 kindly drop the package and follow this [Guide](https://update.angular.io/) for upgradation

Answer (score 0):

add forms and router to the package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
...
"@angular/forms":   "^5.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
...
}
```

then try :

```
npm install
```

Comment: thanks fateme... i already have these dependencies as -  "@angular/router": "^6.0.0", "@angular/forms": "6.0.0",... But anyways npm install worked for @angular/..